# How to use Httpswebrequest class in asp. Net application when FIPS mode is enabled?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, fips

I have an application which uses httpswebrequest to get xml from server. 
But when windows operating systems FIPS is enabled, httpswebrequest.getresponse() function throws exception. 
It is actually MD5CryptoServiceProvider class error inside of httpswebrequest.getresponse() call stack , because it is not complaint with FIPS. 
 Is it any solution to use above method when FIPS is enable?

Can i forcefully set httpwebrequest's inner cryptography method etc.?

Log:
Cannot connect to the device.  Please check the device. System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

at         System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
   at     System.Net.HttpDigest.Interpret(String challenge, Int32 startingPoint, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
   at     System.Net.DigestClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
   at     System.Net.DigestClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
   at     System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
   at      System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
   at    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
   at    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
   at     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception)
   at     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at      km.Common.Communication.Http.CanGetHttpWebResponse(CommunicationInfo communicationInfo)

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: @mason, error and log are added in my question.